# Identifying connected Device Router on Local Area Network using Python

Tags: python, network-programming, lan, mac-address, identification

So I have 4 routers and 1 PC with 4 devices that connect to the closest router. So What I want to do is write a script in python that is running on the PC (Windows) and that PC is connected to 1 main router and that router connects to the other 3 routers.

> 1 PC -> Main Router (WiFi Enabled) -> 3 Other Routers (WiFi Enabled)

The bracelet (a WiFi enabled device) will connect to the nearest WiFi Router available of the 4 routers. I want to detect to which router is that bracelet connected to via a Python script. 
I can make the Bracelet's IP Address Static as well but I was hoping to identify them using the MAC Address.
I can edit the routers configuration via web-page if needed.

Do ask for any clarifications if needed.

Hoping to hear soon.

Edit_1:  Not to be confused with me asking for the whole code, I am in search of the right functions that can be used for this process and what are the possible configurations that I should set the router to.

Edit_2: Below is a sample code which allows for pinging IP's. So how can I get their MAC address (function) and also ping to other access points? I can alter properties of the routers.

```
import socket
from datetime import datetime

net = input("Enter the IP address: ") #e.g. is 192.168.18.1
net1 = net.split('.')
a = '.'

net2 = net1[0] + a + net1[1] + a + net1[2] + a
st1 = int(input("Enter the Starting Number: ")) #e.g. 1
en1 = int(input("Enter the Last Number: ")) #e.g. 10
en1 = en1 + 1

t1 = datetime.now()

def scan(addr):
   s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)
   result = s.connect_ex((addr,135))
   if result == 0:
      return 1
   else :
      return 0

def run1():
   for ip in range(st1,en1):
      addr = net2 + str(ip)
      if (scan(addr)):
         print (addr , "is live")

run1()
t2 = datetime.now()
total = t2 - t1
print ("Scanning completed in: " , total)
```

Edit_3: This searches out the MAC Address as well.

```
from scapy.all import ARP, Ether, srp

target_ip = "192.168.18.1/24"
# IP Address for the destination
# create ARP packet
arp = ARP(pdst=target_ip)
# create the Ether broadcast packet
# ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff MAC address indicates broadcasting
ether = Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
# stack them
packet = ether/arp

result = srp(packet, timeout=3, verbose=0)[0]

# a list of clients, we will fill this in the upcoming loop
clients = []

for sent, received in result:
    # for each response, append ip and mac address to `clients` list
    clients.append({'ip': received.psrc, 'mac': received.hwsrc})


# print clients
print("Available devices in the network:")
print("IP" + " "*18+"MAC")
for client in clients:
    print("{:16}    {}".format(client['ip'], client['mac']))

    if (client['mac'] == "f4:f5:e8:37:67:92"):  #Testing mac address filter
        print("Success")
```

Comment: `if not code: print("No Help")`

Comment: You might have confused Stack Overflow with a free programming service.

Comment: A good Samaritan can pop up! :-D. But Point! Ill post the code I have been working on in a while. Even like a way towards the function call that can be used can help a lot.